# Dell UEFI0023: Bios is unable to send the End of POST message to Management Engine because it is not responding

Tags: dell-poweredge, bios, drac, firmware

After updating firmware on a Dell PowerEdge R730xd we received the following error message:

[image: UEFI0023: Bios is unable to send the End of POST message to Management Engine]

> UEFI0023: BIOS is unable to send the End of POST message to Management
>   Engine because the Management Engine is not responding.
>
> Description: The End of POST message could not be sent to the
>   Management Engine because the Management Engine is not responding.
>   Recommended Action: Remove input power from the system, wait for 30
>   seconds, and re-apply input power. Turn on the system.
>
> System has halted due to critical issue(s)!

This server is in a remote datacenter without remote power management. Is there anyway we can fix this issue without physically pulling the power cables? We tried multiple power cycles and using `racadm -r dracname -u username -p password racreset soft` to power cycle the DRAC but it still has the same error when booting.

Answer (score 3):

You can try changing the power supply hot spare options in the DRAC, which sometimes causes the input power to disconnect briefly and restart the management engine.

1. Open Power / Thermal, Power Configuration tab, Power Configuration sub-tab (See image below)
2. Write down the current settings for Redundancy and Hot Spare
3. Set the Power Supply Options, Redundancy Policy to Not Redundant
4. Enable the Hot Spare option
5. Select PS1 and apply
6. Switch to the Power Control sub-tab, select Power Cycle System (cold boot), and apply (No need to wait for system to reload)
7. Back on the Power Configuration sub-tab, select PS2 and apply
8. Cycle system power (cold boot) again
9. Back on the Power Configuration sub-tab, select PS1 and apply
10. Cycle system power (cold boot) again

[image: Power / Thermal, Power Configuration tab, Power Configuration sub-tab]

After toggling the settings a few times see if the server will boot. If it works, make sure to return the power configuration settings to their previous values.